# Let $\{p,q\}$ be linearly independent polynomials. Show that $\{p,q,pq\}$ is linearily independent if and only if $1\leq deg(p)$ and $1\leq deg(q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $\{p,q\}$ be linearly independent polynomials. Show that $\{p,q,pq\}$ is linearily independent if and only if $1\leq deg(p)$ and $1\leq deg(q)$

**My Proof Attempt**

$[\rightarrow]$ If $\operatorname{deg}(q) = \operatorname{deg}(p)=0$, then they are all constants. Hence, by finding a common factor I can find $pa_1+qa_2+pqa_3=0$ such that not all $a_i = 0$. Hence $1 \leq \operatorname{deg}(q)$ and $1 \leq \operatorname{deg}(p)$.

$[\leftarrow]$ if $1\leq \operatorname{deg}(p)$ and $1\leq \operatorname{deg}(q)$ then $ \operatorname{deg}(p)\operatorname{deg}(q)< \operatorname{deg}(pq)$. A higher degree polynomial can not be written as a sum of lower degrees. Hence $\{p,q,pq\}$ must be linearly independent. QED

**My Proof Attempt II (from suggestions edited, second part)**

$[\rightarrow]$ Contrapositive: $\operatorname{deg}(q)< 
 1 $ OR $\operatorname{deg}(p)<1$. WLOG, $p$ and $q$ are constants. Hence, by finding a common factor I can find $pa_1+qa_2+pqa_3=0$ such that not all $a_i = 0$. Hence $1 \leq \operatorname{deg}(q)$ and $1 \leq \operatorname{deg}(p)$.

$[\leftarrow]$ if $1\leq \operatorname{deg}(p)$ and $1\leq \operatorname{deg}(q)$ then $ \operatorname{deg}(p)< \operatorname{deg}(pq)$ and $\operatorname{deg}(q)< \operatorname{deg}(pq)$. A higher degree polynomial can not be written as a sum of lower degrees. Hence $\{p,q,pq\}$ must be linearly independent, since we know $\{p,q\}$ is L.I. and pq can not be written as a sum of $p$ and $q$. QED

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first look at your forward direction (which I think you're handling via contraposition):

Namely, the negation of "$1 \le \deg(p)$ *and* $1 \le \deg(q)$" is "$1 > \deg(p)$ *or* $1 > \deg(q)$". So the start of this proof should be "WOLOG, $p$ is a constant." I think you'll find that the fix is minor though.

Now, the backward direction:

It concerned me that you didn't use the hypothesis that $\{p, q\}$ are linearly independent. Moreover, your inequality $\deg(p) \deg(q) < \deg(pq)$ isn't correct: take $p = x^2$ and $q = x^3$, so that $pq = x^5$ has degree strictly smaller than 6! I am happy to provide hints on how to incorporate these ideas.

**Edit**: Backwards direction looks great. (You showed in effect that $pq$ is outside of the span of $\langle p, q \rangle$ due to degree considerations.) However, for the forward direction the WLOG is that only one polynomial is a constant.

Comment: I have now made an update to the second part. mainly, I know that $deg(p) < deg(pq)$ which allows me to say that the sum of lower degree polynomials cannot equal a higher degree.

Comment: I added an edit addressing your new solution. Nice job on the updates